# Dependency gets removed from bower

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using AngularJS for my web app, and yeoman for setting up my environment. I want to add this [markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive) to my dependencies. I installed everything, and still: in the bower.json file the entry is missing.

So i added the path to my file in

1. bower.json (just the entry)
2. karma.conf.js (the path)

and i also added the path in my index.html file. When i run grunt serve, the path in the index.html file gets removed and i'm getting this error message:

```
showdown was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "app/bower_components/showdown" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.
```

> What can i do so the link stays in my index.html file?

I know, i can add it after the server started, but every time i restart grunt, the script-tag gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i continued trying to fix this. What i found out:

> Bower needs the *.js file in the root folder of the plugin. The showdown.js file was inside a "compressed" folder.

Maybe interesting for future "file was not injected" problems.

Comment: that's one thing i hate about bower. no standardization.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it but including an override inside the projects bower.json file telling it which file to use for showdown

```
"overrides": {
        "showdown": {
            "main": [
                "src/showdown.js"
            ]
        }
    }
```